# Is there a site focused on digital tech innovation in healthcare?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site or a community that focuses on digital tech and innovation in  healthcare?

I am looking to connect with other technologists working in the health space or interested in the healthcare space.

Comment: there is [medical sciences.se](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but I'm not sure if they are open for that subject.

Comment: There was once an [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposal (and definitely with a tech component). I don't know the status of it, but it should not be difficult to find.